# Using proxy to make request results in bad request (400) error code

Tags: node.js, fetch, node-fetch

I'm using node-fetch and https-proxy-agent to make a request using a proxy, however, I get a 400 error code from the site I'm scraping only when I send the `agent`, without it, everything works fine.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import Proxy from 'https-proxy-agent';

const ip = PROXIES[Math.floor(Math.random() * PROXIES.length)]; // PROXIES is a list of ips
const proxyAgent = Proxy(`http://${ip}`);

fetch(url, {
    agent: proxyAgent,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.72 Safari/537.36'
    }
}).then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)
```

This results in a 400 error code like so:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. If you want to reproduce the issue, I'm scraping `https://azlyrics.com`. Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. I did not notice I was making a request to a https site with a http proxy. The site was using https protocol but the proxies were http only. Changing to https proxies works. Thank you.